# call stored procedure in select statement in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a stored procedure and would like to reuse it in batch call. I tried the following:

```
CALL some_sproc(SELECT TOP 10 colum1, column2 FROM SomeTable)
```

but this does not work. Guess it is impossible in snowflake (Google has not resulted in any hits ...)? Thanks!

Comment: You are wanting to pass in the values returned in a result set to a stored procedure that would then run over and over again for each row? This is not how stored procedures work in any RDBMS. You could put that SELECT inside the stored procedure, and then iterate the result set using a cursor, wherein you would run whatever logic the proc does on each iteration. OR... you could, in another stored procedure or outside scripting language, get that result set back and then call the stored procedure repeatedly for each row.

Comment: thanks - I could swear I have done something along those lines in sql server ... btw this is most likely not best practise - is more to get something to work ...

Comment: " I could swear I have done something along those lines in sql server" - User Defined Table Type?

Comment: no control over what exits ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call the procedure multiple times based on query input you could use loop:

```
DECLARE
  c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TOP 10 colum1, column2 FROM SomeTable;
BEGIN
  FOR record IN c1 DO
       LET col1 <type> := record.column1;
       LET col2 <type> := record.column2;
       CALL some_sproc(:col1, :col2);
  END FOR;
  RETURN 'Success';
END;
```

---

Alternatively rewrite the stored procedure to take input which is not scalar but for instance an array:

```
CALL some_sproc(
   SELECT ARRAY_AGG(obj) 
   FROM (SELECT TOP 10 OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('column1', colum1,
       ,'column2', column2) AS obj FROM SomeTable)
);
```

Comment: amazing - will have a look - thanks.

Comment: my use case is that the sproc invocation returns one row of data and I would like to return all (top 10) rows. is this possible? Thanks!